# how to remove two columns in excel using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel-automation

Sample data:

`|   | Unnamed: 0 | Status                  | Clarification Opened | Failed |
|---|------------|-------------------------|----------------------|--------|
| 1 | 1          | P0 Dry Run - 12/02/18   |                      | 2.0    |
| 2 | 2          | P1 Test Plan - 06/02/18 |                      | 2.0    |
| 3 | 3          | P2 Test plan - 03/01/18 | 2.0                  | 21.0   |`

I need to know how to remove the unwanted first two columns and with the size of columns will vary

Comment: Can you explain more? Do you want remove all column with `Unnamed` ? First column is `index` ? `(print (df.index))` ? Also the best is add some code, what you try.

Comment: I try with usecols, but it won't works because i need to change the column size everytime

Comment: Is it possible to remove the unnamed field

Comment: `df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed')]` ?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael it works. Can I know more about that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove all columns witch not contains `Unnamed` - it means need all columns which not contains `Unnamed`:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use this:

```
# import excel
df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
# remove columns
df.drop(axis=1, labels=list_with_column_name_to_remove, inplace=True)
# save excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file_name.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```